# Flutter how to get latitude, longitude using geolocator package?

Tags: flutter, dart, package

> Flutter how to get latitude, longitude using geolocator package?
> Already gave permissions both android and ios, downloaded package using pubspec.yaml. I don't understand why can't print longitude and latitude to console? tried write print(position), print(position.longitude()), print(position.latitue()).

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';


class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
 void getLocation() async {
   print('Printing text before getCurrentLocation()');
   Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
   print(position);


}

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: Center(
       child: RaisedButton(
         color: Colors.red,
         onPressed: () {
           getLocation();
         },
         child: Text('Get Location'),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
} ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `position.latitude` or `position.longitude`. You've used `position.longitude()` & `position.latitude()`, which is incorrect.

Also, you need to add `async-await` for `onPressed` callback. I'm assuming that you've added permissions in manifest & granted the necessary permissions as well.

**Method**

```dart
void getLocation() async {
   Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
   print(position.latitude);
   print(position.longitude);
}
```

**Widget**

```dart
RaisedButton(
    color: Colors.red,
    onPressed: () async {
        await getLocation();
    },
    child: Text('Get Location'),
),
```

Comment: thank you after added async, await to onPressed. Everything worked.