# How to get current location latitude and longitude in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any other flutter plugin which get current location latitude and longitude, i know there are two plugins available which is `geolocator` and `location`. But i use these two plugins and noted some problems are:

1. If i use `geolocator` plugin then i get current location latitude and longitude but problem is i have to wait at least 5-10 seconds then only i get latitude and longitude which is not a good user experience.
2. If i use `location` plugin then sometime i get null in `location.getLocation()`. I raised this issue in there github but no response.
   **Note: I have also checked my internet connection and it is absolutely very fast speed.**
   So is there any other plugin available other than `geolocator` and `location` plugin?

> Geolocator Plugin Code

```
var latitude = "";
var longitude = "";
Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
    desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
latitude = position.latitude.toString();
longitude = position.longitude.toString();
print(latitude);
print(longitude);
```

Comment: Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69660808/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68483238/13997210) hope it's helpful to you

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Yes i use that package but problem is taking lot of time atleast 5-10 seconds to get latitude and longitude

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I have updated my question and also added code, it is taking lot of time to get latitude and longitude

Comment: Yes I think it will take some time so I will suggest you call your function inside `setState((){})` refer **setState** [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I am doing this in a class not in stateful widget.

Comment: Which widget do you used Stateful or Stateless?

Comment: `class DataService {
Future<List<RecommendedForYouData>?> makeRequestRecommendedForYou(
      BuildContext context) async {
Location location = new Location();
var latitude = "";
    var longitude = "";
    final _locationData = await location.getLocation();
    latitude = _locationData.latitude.toString();
    longitude = _locationData.longitude.toString();
}
}`

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil This code which i mentioned in comment is the `location` package and above which i mentioned in question is `geolocator` plugin and both is in `DataService` class

Comment: Can you tell me you try my answer? Because it's very good working for me

Comment: Yes i tried your code but it is getting long time in iOS devices

Comment: Ok go to this answer provide documentation url and add some contents in **iOS folder** for `info.plist` file

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I already added some contents in `info.plist` which are `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription`,`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`,`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter how to get latitude, longitude using geolocator package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66185682/flutter-how-to-get-latitude-longitude-using-geolocator-package)